# How to convert a CSV to JSON array using the Miller command line tool?

Tags: miller

Using the [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) command line tool I want to convert a CSV file with headers into a JSON array.

Currently I am using this command: `mlr --icsv --ojson cat sample.csv > sample.json`

It is outputting JSON, but not in array format.

This is the sample CSV input:

```
Keyword, Weight, Quantity
Apple, 10, 2345
Orange, 23, 467
Banana, 2345, 2345
```

And this is the output I am getting from Miller:

```
{ "Keyword": "Apple", "Weight": 10, "Quantity": 2345 }
{ "Keyword": "Orange", "Weight": 23, "Quantity": 467 }
{ "Keyword": "Banana", "Weight": 2345, "Quantity": 2345 }
```

As you can see this output is JSON Lines, not an array format.

I want the JSON to be an array, like this:

```
[
    { "Keyword": "Apple", "Weight": 10, "Quantity": 2345 },
    { "Keyword": "Orange", "Weight": 23, "Quantity": 467 },
    { "Keyword": "Banana", "Weight": 2345, "Quantity": 2345 }
]
```

What is the correct Miller command for that?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.

You need to use `--jlistwrap`.

So the full command becomes: `mlr --icsv --ojson --jlistwrap cat sample.csv > sample.json`

Which outputs this:

```
[
{ "Keyword": "Apple", "Weight": 10, "Quantity": 2345 }
,{ "Keyword": "Orange", "Weight": 23, "Quantity": 467 }
,{ "Keyword": "Banana", "Weight": 2345, "Quantity": 2345 }
]
```

It's not formatted beautifully (commas on the wrong line, and not indented) but it's a valid JSON array.

After running through a tool to auto-format the JSON it would look like this:

```
[
   {
      "Keyword":"Apple",
      "Weight":10,
      "Quantity":2345
   },
   {
      "Keyword":"Orange",
      "Weight":23,
      "Quantity":467
   },
   {
      "Keyword":"Banana",
      "Weight":2345,
      "Quantity":2345
   }
]
```